# How do I use python3 argparse to read and write a pcap file between a specific time frame?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, argparse

My specific questions are below.

1. How do I use the python argparse library to search and read a packet capture file (PCAP) for a specific time frame?(example from start time to end time, and between two times given by the user)
2. How do I read a pcap for that specific time frame and then output another pcap file?

additional note: I can read the pcap files however I can not understand how to use argparse to write a pcap file. See below for more details.

I am writing a python3 packet analysis program and I would like to search the pcap or pcaps between a start and stop time range. I am using the following libraries and I would like to stick to parsing the pcaps with dpkt.

```
import os
import sys
import socket
import glob
import datetime
import argparse
from binascii import hexlify
import dpkt
```

I have some functions to validate the dates and times submitted. In the end I would like to add seconds, and milliseconds, see below

```
def valid_date_type(arg_date_str):
    """custom argparse *date* type for user dates values given from the command line"""
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(arg_date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Given Date ({0}) not valid! Expected format, YYYY-MM-DD!".format(arg_date_str)
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)

def valid_datetime_type(arg_datetime_str):
    """custom argparse type for user datetime values given from the command line"""
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(arg_datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Given Datetime ({0}) not valid! Expected format, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'!".format(arg_datetime_str)
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
```

I am able to parse the packets effectively and all of my argparse arguments work correctly except the date and time arguments. Below are a few arguments

```
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is a program to fetch information from pcaps')
    #below is the first argument to read the pcap into fetchit. The type is read binary(rb)
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--read", required=False, type=argparse.FileType('rb'), help="reads a pcapfile")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--session", required=False, action='store_true', help="print the raw session data from a pcap")
parser.add_argument("-dns", "--dns", required=False, action='store_true', help="use the dns decoder")
    #below are my switched for dates and times, these do not work yet. 
    parser.add_argument('-sd', "--startdate", required=False, dest='start_datetime', type=valid_datetime_type, help='start datetime in format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"')
    parser.add_argument('-ed', "--enddate", required=False, dest='end_datetime', type=valid_datetime_type, help='end datetime in format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The program reads the entire pcap and then outputs stdout to the terminal. I've tried a million ways to read a pcap file and then write a pcap file or text file with argparse. The main way that I write the out.txt file is with the following

```
program.py -r file.pcap -s > out.txt
```

Thank you in advance for any future help.

J

Comment: Use `argparse` to parse the parameters provided by your user, the command line.  Actually doing stuff, such as read and writing files is the responsibility of your own code.  All the `read` argument does is open that file.

Comment: Does the output to `stdout` with `> out.txt` work?  It's not entirely clear, but are you looking for another way of writing to a file?

Comment: the output to stdout does work and I hope this is only temporary. I would like to use argparse to write the file. I understand that the reading and writing is the responsibility of my own code. The reading is not the problem. I don't understand how to write the file using argparse. I've read many examples but none of them talk about writing pcaps or how to get argparse to call the function that writes the file....any advice would be great. My main questions are above numbered 1 and 2. :-)

Comment: Just to be more clear, I can read a full pcap from start packet to end packet, but I can not read a specific time range from the start packet to end packet issued by the user within a pcap file. For example, lets say the pcap file has packets from 2019-02-17 21:00 until 2019-02-17 23:00. I would like my user to read the pcap and only extract the time from 22:00 until 22:30.  Editcap can do this with -A and -B and I could use Editcap if I could also use a subprocess function and have argparse call that function but I'm not sure if that is the best way.....hope it helps add some more details.

Comment: The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736090/how-to-run-certain-function-based-on-command-line-input-given-in-python shows a good way of organizing a script using `argparse`.  Most of the functionality of the function should be outside of the parser, and usable without using the parser.

Comment: A `FileType` with `w` mode can open a output file.  But In PY3 it is better to use files in a `with` context, which takes care of opening and closing.  We know nothing about your `pcap` file, so can't help you with the reading.  `argparse` can't help either, because it isn't a file reader.  Let me stress, `argparse` is used to fetch values from the command line.  It does not read files, write files or call subprocesses.  Your own code does that.

Comment: @hpaulj i totally understand. I am having a hard time finding examples on how to link arguments with actions for example reading one file and then writing something else from that file which is combining arguments. From what i know argparse should be able to process the user commands to get that accomplished.  The python code that i created reads the pcap. Argparse just points the switch or --read to my script. I cant figure out how to point the argparse --output to my script. I also cant figure out how to do that while using specific start and stop times.

Comment: This could be a actions issue or even a parent issue but i dont know where to get started. Ive googled it for two week before asking. I have also read the argparse tutorials from start to finish.

Comment: Im re-reading my questions and they are not as specific as i wanted them to be. Sorry im not using the argparse library to write my python code to do things. Im using the argparse library to get user input. I dont understand how to combine the tasks together and i dont understand how to get the arguments to run the functiona that i create.

Comment: Do a `print(args)`.  Then look at `arg.read`, `args.startdate`, `args.enddate`, etc.

Comment: Ok i will try that and it sounds like a great idea. I think my actual question is how do i combine a tool like ettercap with the -a and -b switches with argparse? In one of my programs i can use tshark to read a filter if the filter is in a variable. My function works with argparse to both execute tshark and the filter which then prints to screen.  How can i use argparse to have the user enter the filter?  Is that done within one argument or two arguments, one child and one parent?

Comment: Today I managed to get the writing to a file issue working.